# The existence of a variety generated in low degree that is epsilon-close to a fixed variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, inner-product

Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional complex vector space endowed with the standard Hermitian inner product, let $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ be an algebraic set that forms a cone, and let $1>\epsilon>0$ be a number. I would like to find an algebraic set $Y$ that is generated in low degree and is "$\epsilon$-close" to $X$ in the sense that for all unit vectors $y \in Y$ there exists a unit vector $x \in X$ for which
\begin{align}
|\langle x,y\rangle |^2\geq 1-\epsilon.
\end{align}

As a particular example, I would be interested in the case when $X$ is just a finite union of 1-dimensional linear subspaces.

I realize that this question is quite broad... I suppose it is mostly a reference request for any work done on questions like this.

As Lev Borisov correctly points out, if $Y \supseteq X$, then $Y$ cannot be generated in degree less than the degree in which $X$ is generated.

Comment: Is it clear that every variety is close to itself? If you require this closeness for all pairs of points… Maybe it should be something like, for all $x$ there’s a close enough $y$, and vice versa?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: What do you want as far as dimensions of $X$ and $Y$ go? I am assuming you are not interested in $Y $ being the union of $X$ and a line, right?

Comment: @LevBorisov X is fixed, and I want to choose Y to be generated in the smallest possible degree. I don’t care about dimension. Would the union of X and a line be generated in low degree for some reason? If so I’m interested.

Comment: I would imagine that the union of X and a line would be generated in degree one greater than X, so this wouldn’t be interesting. I want to reduce the generator degree

Comment: The problem is that if there are no polynomials of small degree that vanish on $X$, then there there would not be any that vanish on a larger set $Y$. Perhaps you want $Y$ to be "close to $X$ but not containing it"?

Comment: @LevBorisov Of course! Thank you for setting me straight. Yes, "close to $X$ but not containing it" is definitely my follow-up question. I will adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "low degree"? Is the degree bounded by a constant independent of both $\epsilon$ and the set $Y$?

Comment: @WillSawin I am mostly vaguely interested in what (if anything) is known/obvious for questions like this, but here is a concrete question: For fixed $d$, what is the smallest $\epsilon$ for which there exists an algebraic set $Y$ that is $\epsilon$-close to $X$ and is generated in degree $d$? For $d$ being equal to the generator degree of $X$, we can take $\epsilon=0$. What can we do for $d$ less than the generator degree of $X$? Starting with the case in which $X$ has projective dimension zero seems like it might be a good starting point.

Comment: In the worst case $X$ contains a $\epsilon/10$-net in the unit sphere, i.e. for each point in the unit sphere, $X$ contains a point within $\epsilon/10$ of it. So $Y$ is $\epsilon$-close to $X$ only if $Y$ is $11\epsilon/10$ close to the whole space. So it's essentially equivalent to a question about low-degree algebraic sets whose points are $\epsilon$-dense. For fixed $n$, one can obtain such a set with $\epsilon \approx d^{ - (n-1)/(2n-1)}$ by counting, and I think one can't do better than $\epsilon \approx d^{-1}$ by examining the Laplacian.

Comment: Actually if $Y\supseteq X$, then $Y$ could be generated in lower degree than $X$. E.g. $X$ could be cut out by quadrics and cubics but if one considers quadrics only, then one can get some $Y$. So maybe an easier question is not "generated" but simply having a hypersurface of small degree passing through it.

Comment: Then it is a question of whether one can find a hypersurface $f=0$ whose distance from each of the points in $X$ is smaller than some number. It feels like a sensible question of minimization of maximum distance, although some $L^2$ norm may be more tractable.